# Why do Postgres Hstore indexes work for ? (operator) and not for EXIST (function)?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, hstore

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/hstore.html states:

```
hstore has GiST and GIN index support for the @>, ?, ?& and ?| operators
```

Yet the indexes [don't work for the `EXIST` function](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/BUG-7715-hstore-quot-exists-quot-should-use-same-index-as-quot-quot-operator-td5734358.html), which appears to be equivalent to the `?` operator.

What is the difference between operators and functions that makes it harder to index one or the other?

Might future versions of the Hstore extension make these truly equivalent?

Comment: EXISTS is not a function but a relational operator. What's inside the `EXISTS(...)` subqury? (probably one of the operators you mentioned)

Comment: For example, `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar ? 'aaa'` will use the index but `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE EXIST(bar, 'aaa')` will not - even though the queries are otherwise functionally equivalent

Comment: Ist there actually a function called `EXIST`, or do you mean the `EXISTS` operator ?

Comment: the hstore extension defines the function `EXIST` - please RTM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup the documentation for "CREATE OPERATOR CLASS" which describes how you can create indexing methods for arbitrary operators. You also need to use "CREATE OPERATOR" to create an operator based on the EXIST function first.

(Caveat: I have no experience with hstore)

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createoperator.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createopclass.html

Comment: so do you think there was a reason that the hstore contributors didn' do this for `EXIST` ?

Comment: As I said I don't know hstore specifically, but from glancing over it, maybe operator ? *is* wrapping the exist function in the proper way already. Note that in general functions cannot be used in indices, since they could be indeterministic and depend on non argument data, and only operators provide the necessary meta data for index use.

Comment: I [proposed a fix to pgsql-hackers](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5113206D.2060107@abshere.net)

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:  PostgreSQL functions are planner-opaque.  The planner has no way of knowing that the operator and the function are semantically equivalent.   This comes up a lot.

PostgreSQL does have functional indexes so you can index outputs of immutable functions but this may not quite make things work perfectly well here since you'd probably be able to only index which rows return true for a given call, but this could still be very useful with partial indexes.  For example you could always do something like:

```
CREATE INDEX bar_has_aaa ON foo(exists(bar, 'aaa'));
```

or

```
CREATE INDEX bar_has_aaa ON foo(id) where exists (bar, 'aaa');
```

But I don' see this going exactly where you need it to go.  Hopefully it points you in the right direction though.

Edit:  The following strikes me as a better workaround.  Suppose we have a table foo:

```
 CREATE TABLE foo (
        id serial,
        bar hstore
 );
```

We can create a table method bar_keys:

```
CREATE FUNCTION bar_keys(foo) RETURNS text[] IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
    SELECT akeys($1.bar);
$$;
```

Then we can index that using GIN:

```
 CREATE INDEX foo_bar_keys_idx ON foo USING gin(bar_keys(foo));
```

And we can use it in our queries:

```
  SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.bar_keys @> array['aaa'];
```

That should use an index.  Note you could just index/use akeys directly, but I think a virtual column leads to cleaner syntax.

Comment: is there a way, in the hstore contrib source code, to mark them as equivalent or deliberately enable indexing without user intervention?

Comment: no.   I have been thinking about this however.  I am going to update my answer with another better workaround.